# opendax frontend not working properly

Tags: docker

I would like to run https://github.com/openware/opendax
All my containers are running in docker. `rake service:all`. I made config to
/etc/hosts and app.yaml. I have this blank [page](https://ibb.co/G3Zsp3M).
I am trying to figure where is problem. Probably in **baseapp** frontent.
Can somebody point me to right direction what to looking at?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: I am checking with `docker logs container` but nothing suspicious found